# How to get the url that called the controller in a Spring thymeleaf application

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

I've got two pages that link to the same new page. What I need to be able to do is pass the current page so that the new page can return to it after it has done what needs to be done.

Suppose I have two pages:
`/user/46#updateInfo` and
`/child/993#updateInfo`

Both pages have a button
`<a id="upload-image" th:href="@{/documents/upload/__${id}__}" class="btn btn-primary"> Upload Image </a>`
which triggers the controller:

```
@GetMapping({documentType}/{userId})
public ModelAndView uploadImage(ModelAndView mav, 
                                @PathVariable(name="documentType") Optional<DocumentType> documentType, 
                                @PathVariable(name="userId") Optional<String> userId,
                                @RequestParam(name="returnUrl") Optional<String> returnUrl) {

   // do stuff here
   mav.addObject("returnUrl", returnUrl);
   mav.setViewName("uploadImages");
   return mav;
}
```

I've tried adding in the script section of the pages with the upload button the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#upload-image').prop("value", window.location.pathname + window.location.hash);
   $('#upload-image').prop("returnUrl", window.location.pathname + window.location.hash);
}
```

But that value doesn't show up in the controller.  And I'm thinking there has to be an easier way.

Again, the goal is when the new page is loaded (in this example `uploadImages` page), the user will either upload an image or click the Cancel button and then be returned to either the `/user/46#updateInfo` or
`/child/993#updateInfo` page, which ever page initially called the uploadImages page.

Answer (score 0):

Add HttpServletRequest object to the list of arguments of your controller method and call getRequestURI() method on that object within that controller.That should do the job - the method returns a String containg a full path of requested URI

Comment: The returns the `/documents/upload/__${id}__` part of the URL.  What I'm looking for is the `/user/46#updateInfo`, the referrer, I guess.

Comment: I found httpServletrequest.getHeader("referer") from another post, but the value returned doesn't include the hashmap value from the url.

Comment: "referer" can be easily spoofed and is often blank/empty/null.

Comment: The solution, I think, is to identify the page with a property in a form (with any other data I need), and act on that.